# AJAX sending error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a strange problem with jQuery `ajax` function in my script.

my problem `only` happen on my friend computer but i don't suffer from any thing on my computer.

I tried to make error function property alert error contents but something `strange` happened

```
$.ajax({
    url : EXECUTION_URL + 'ajax/users.php',
    type : 'POST',
    error : function( err1, err2, err3 ) {
        alert(err2 + ' : ' + err3 + ' , ' + err1.responseText);
    },
    data : {
        'value' : 'val',
        'type' : 'email'
    },
    success : function( data, statusText, xhr ) {
        alert(data)
    },
});
```

the important line is : 
`alert(err2 + ' : ' + err3 + ' , '+ err1.responseText)`
but it fire only : `'error: , '` .
 
why this happen ? and how i can know the error of sending this request

Comment: Use the developer tools in just about all the browsers or something like http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: my biggest problem is i don't can see the error on my computer

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to get the correct error like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Remove the error function in your ajax call and then call your ajax method. In case, there's some error, the ajax setup would catch it and display a proper alert based on the error that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the objects you're trying to alert can't be converted to string (for the alert text). Try using a `console.log`.
Then you'll know what's happening and you'll be able to fix the problem.

Comment: mmmm , i think all of them are string by jquery defaults i will try console.log

Comment: At least err1 can't be a string as you're accessing one of it's elements (.responseText)

Comment: err1 is an object , err1.responseText is a text ? or object ?

Comment: err1.responseText is a string, of course. But you're trying to alert err2 and err3, and one of them is an object, according to jQuery's docs: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

Answer (score 0):

Your error function

```
error : function( err1, err2, err3 ) {  // is equivalent to 

error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)  

Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror".
```

Maybe the err2 is null and that's the reason you see no output for err2